# Java serializable classes generated uuid does not work for ehcache

Tags: java, ehcache, serializable

I'm developing a project that I need to cache some classes which requires for those classes to implement serializable. The error I receive was similar to this "classcastexception: class demo.x.t.y.A(any class I serialized) cannot be cast to class demo.x.t.y.A". I mean classes are exact same of each other.

After depth trying I found that program works, when I used java's own classes that implements serializable instead of my serializable classes. I generated uuid in netbeans with a plugin that is suggested in web site of netbeans. I'm pretty sure that reason was my own generated uuids but why uuids do not work? I do not make any changes on classes after generating uuids.

In java default classes above serialversionUUID there is a comment exactly like this "/** use serialVersionUID from JDK 1.0.2 for interoperability */". Does it mean i should generate uuid using jdk1.0.2? I tried many things and open to any solution. Thanks for any reply.

To help developers who may encounter with the same issue I have a solution which I do not want to use. Instead of caching whole class, you can cache each variable separately.

Since its my first question, sorry for any mistake I made writing question.

Edit: 
 I'm using servlet. When I run servlet it works fine but after another deploy it fails.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably not caused by serial version UIDs, but by classloader issues. you probably try to cast an object whose class was loaded by a class loader A (the class loader used by EHCache) to a class loaded by class loader B (your webapp's class loader).

Without more details, it's hard to tell what you should do, but make sure your class can be loaded by one and only one class loader. For example, if the class is both in the webapp's classpath (WEB-INF/lib) and in the server classpath, it might be the issue.

Comment: To test if I made any mistake using ehcache, I created new projects with very simple classes do not think they are replicated any where else but I will look around for class loader issue. Thanks for the reply. I will try to give feedback If I make any progress.